# How would I use jQuery's slideDown() on a set of new rows added to a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm adding several new rows to an existing table with an event. I want these new rows to show up with the slideDown() effect.

Using slideDown() on the entire table will slide down the whole table and not just the new rows. I can't make another table because the columns won't align. And if I make the columns of the new table the same pixel size as the old table, it won't resize correctly when the page resizes or other stuff is added/removed to the DOM.

[It says here](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/tbody/) that several tbody tags can be in one table. I tried adding new ones and it didn't work. But even if it did it doesn't matter because if I use the slide animations on the tbody tags it doesn't animate it just instantly disappears/appears.

Comment: Unfortunately I think your username may be prophetic in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. slideDown does not work in TRs. To solve the problem I've put a Div inside the TDs.

Comment: wow it does kinda work. It looks a bit weird because if it's too slow you can notice it's not really sliding down but each cell is sliding down both vertically and horizontally. But it's better than no slide at all. :D

Comment: Sorry bu I really dont know. In my sample it worked for a single row at time.

Comment: I know it is a work around, but the time I had that problem I did not find nothing better.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work, by the way, is because behind the scenes slideDown works by changing the `display` style from `none` to `block`. However, in the case of table cells/rows the display types are different (`table-cell` and `table-row`, respectively).